# python matplotlib.pyplot chops data when streaming

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to stream continuous data over the network to matplotlib. In principle this is working, but occasionally - esp. at startup of the UI or when I resize the window - the data gets chopped.
I tried thread locking but no success.
A little generator that I run over netcat:

```py
from random import random as rand
while True:
    print(f'{rand()};{rand()};{rand()};{rand()};{rand()}')
```

run over netcat:

```
python3 genrndcsv.py | nc localhost 5027
```

then I run my UI client:

```py
import matplotlib
import collections
#selecting the right backend, change qt4agg to your desired backend
##matplotlib.use('qt4agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import socket
import threading
from random import random as rand

lock = threading.Lock()

#command to open the pipe
#datapipe = open('path to your pipe','r')
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(('', 5027))
socket.listen(5)
client, address = socket.accept()
print("{} connected".format( address ))

#amount of data to be displayed at once, this is the size of the x axis
#increasing this amount also makes plotting slightly slower
data_amount = 1000

#set the size of the deque object
datalist = collections.deque([0]*data_amount,data_amount)

#configure the graph itself
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([0,]*data_amount)

#size of the y axis is set here
ax.set_ylim(0,256)

def update(data):
        line.set_ydata(data)
        return line,

def data_gen1():
    f = client.makefile()
    while True:
        #l = f'{rand()};{rand()};{rand()};{rand()};{rand()}'
        l = f.readline()
        eol = l.find('\n')
        if eol < 0:
            print(f'n0pe')
            exit(-1)
        l.strip('\n')
        #print(f't {type(l)} {l}')
        vals = [float(x) for x in l.split(';')]
        #print(f'v {vals[0]}')
        datalist.append(vals[0])
        yield datalist

BLEN=256

def data_gen():
    response = bytearray(b'')
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        if len(response) < BLEN/2:
            rx = client.recv(BLEN)
            print(f'type(rx){type(rx)}')
            if len(rx) > 0:
                print(f'len {len(rx)}')
                response.extend(bytearray(rx))
        eol = response.find(b'\n')
        if eol != -1:
            l = response[:eol]
            ##print(f'len={len(response)} eol={eol} r_pre  {response}')
            print(f'r_pre  {response}')
            response = response[eol+1:]
            print(f'r_post {response}')
            vals = [float(x) for x in l.split(b';')]
            print(f'{vals[0]}')
            print()
            datalist.append(vals[0])
            lock.release()
            yield datalist

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,data_gen1,interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

As you can see I tried datagen1() and a more manual datagen() but both behave the same. I captured the network data and it is OK. However I get huge spikes (which com from misinterpreted strings) like this when I resize the Window:
[spikes in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcuDj.png)

the error becomes very obvious when I log r_pre and r_post in data_gen(): in the the error case r_pre is not equal to the previous r_post.
If I exxagerate resizing the window I quickly run into a parsing error where not only large numbers but '' or ';' or '123.234.345' are interpreted as numbers, which obvously fails:

```
('127.0.0.1', 54281) connected
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 139, in _on_timer
    super()._on_timer()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1216, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1477, in _step
    still_going = super()._step(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1188, in _step
    framedata = next(self.frame_seq)
  File ".\streamtestoffline.py", line 50, in data_gen1
    vals = [float(x) for x in l.split(';')]
  File ".\streamtestoffline.py", line 50, in <listcomp>
    vals = [float(x) for x in l.split(';')]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 139, in _on_timer
    super()._on_timer()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1216, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1477, in _step
    still_going = super()._step(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1188, in _step
    framedata = next(self.frame_seq)
  File ".\streamtestoffline.py", line 50, in data_gen1
    vals = [float(x) for x in l.split(';')]
  File ".\streamtestoffline.py", line 50, in <listcomp>
    vals = [float(x) for x in l.split(';')]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.291439.7957812126795342'
```

any help to make this robust is very much appreciated